# If else Statement inside a attribute and a attribute inside a If else Statement

Tags: php, html, css

I'm working on a  tag where i could have a linked image that has a data map-highlight and how can i make that if else statement work inside a attribute? and on the statement will consist of a another attribute.

here is my code:

```
<map id="ground" name="ground">
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stall s 
    LEFT JOIN tenant t 
    ON t.stall_id = s.stall_id
    LEFT JOIN rent r
    ON r.tenant_id = t.tenant_id 
    AND r.rent_status = 1
    WHERE s.stall_id = 1";          

    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $fetch = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach ($fetch as $key => $value) { ?>
    <area id="9" shape="rect" coords="9,98,46,117" data-toggle="modal" class = "stallstyle1"  
    href="#stall_modal9" 
    value="<?php echo $value['rent_status']?>"
    <?php
    if ($value ['rent_status'] == 1) {
    data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"008000","strokeWidth":3,"fillColor":"7CFC00","fillOpacity":0.6,"alwaysOn":true}'>
     } else {
    data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"FF0000","strokeWidth":3,"fillColor":"FF3333","fillOpacity":0.6,"alwaysOn":true}'>
    }
    ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using of ternary operator is more easy and understandable rather than using if/else. So use ternary operator to get the value of attribute `data-maphilight`.And then use it inside your tag. Hope that the following code will work if you are getting the values from databse.

```
    <map id="ground" name="ground">
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM stall s 
    LEFT JOIN tenant t 
    ON t.stall_id = s.stall_id
    LEFT JOIN rent r
    ON r.tenant_id = t.tenant_id 
    AND r.rent_status = 1
    WHERE s.stall_id = 1";          

    $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $fetch = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach ($fetch as $key => $value){

    $maphilight= ($value['rent_status'] == 1)?'{"strokeColor":"008000","strokeWidth":3,"fillColor":"7CFC00","fillOpacity":0.6,"alwaysOn":true}':'{"strokeColor":"FF0000","strokeWidth":3,"fillColor":"FF3333","fillOpacity":0.6,"alwaysOn":true}';
     ?>
    <area id="9" shape="rect" coords="9,98,46,117" data-toggle="modal" class = "stallstyle1"  
    href="#stall_modal9" value="<?php echo $value['rent_status'];?>" data-maphilight='<?php echo $maphilight;?>'>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The colors are still not changing.

Comment: What is the value of $value['rent_status'].

Comment: the value of the rent_status is 1 and if i change it to 0 the mapping disappears

Comment: just use `($value['rent_status'])?` in the place of `($value['rent_status'] == 1)?` what will happen.

Comment: still nothing happens. because there is no value for the rent_status the mapping is brocken

Comment: Then try it with value of status 1.

Comment: i think the problem is if the value of rent status is 1 it displays nothing no the maphighlight

Comment: yes may be... you have to be sure at what condition it should be shown.

Comment: i think your code is fine. when the value of rent_status is 1. but if the value is not 1 nothing happens. the mapping and the colors of the data-maphilight disappears.

Comment: Yes code is correct but mapping may wrong so check your color mapping and try again.I hope your problem will be solve.

Comment: i got it. the the value of the rent_status = 1 on the sql is the problem

Comment: Yes i have already mention you that code will work  if you are getting the values from database.Congrats..